# gcloud builds triggers create with bitbucket has no manual triggers event option

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, gcloud, google-cloud-build

Trying to create a build with manual trigger using the gcloud utility but couldn't find it in options, while the option is available in console.

[image]

I'm using below syntax:

```
gcloud alpha builds triggers create cloud-source-repositories --name="<TRIGGER_NAME>" --repo="bitbucket_<REPO_NAME>" --branch-pattern="^<BRANCH_NAME>$" --build-config="cloudbuild.yaml" --project=<PROJECT_ID>
```

Any idea how to define this event type ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The current command you are using is presently in [ALPHA](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/builds/triggers/create) status and is subject to change at any time. You may be trying to access an API with an invitation-only early access allowlist if this command fails with API permission problems despite giving the correct project. This documentation was last updated on April 27th, 2021.

It also suggests to use the following command: [gcloud beta builds triggers create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/builds/triggers/create)

Create a build trigger from a Cloud Source Repository with the gcloud beta builds triggers create cloud-source-repositories command.

To establish a push trigger for all branches, follow this example:

```
gcloud beta builds triggers create cloud-source-repositories --name="my-trigger" --service-account="projects/my-project/serviceAccounts/my-byosa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --repo="my-repo" --branch-pattern=".*" --build-config="cloudbuild.yaml"
```

This documentation was last updated on October 29th, 2021.